# Java arrays searching and sorting not working as intended

Tags: java, arrays

I'm currently taking an Introduction to Java class where we are currently on Arrays topics. We have a class lab where are suppose to create a simple array program consisting a two classes (Passenger.java and Demo.java). The array can be of any sizing (minimum 4) and we can hard code details into few elements. We are supposed to create two methods for searching by the ID and name (firstname + lastname), and two methods for sorting (bubble & insertion) by the ID and surname in ascending order.

In my searching methods for both ID and name, I get java.lang.NullPointerException error when I entered a ID that does not exists in Array. It was suppose to return an error message that i have compose if it is not found.

In my sorting methods for ID, I also get java.lang.NullPointerException error after the second loop. For my sorting methods for surname, I don't know how to implement.

Hence may I know, how to solve this couple of issues with a working full code example.

Note:

- I cannot use ArrayList and any Java Arrays classes
- Please treat the Array's element 3 to 8 as initialized with values
- I have viewed this [initialize all variables but still get NullPointerExceptions error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21505312/initialize-all-variables-but-still-get-nullpointerexceptions-error), this [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it), and this [Array Sorting and Searching Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27096968/array-sorting-and-searching-java) and lastly this [Initialized elements getting NullPointerException error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55430449/initialized-elements-getting-nullpointerexception-error)

**Passenger.java**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Passenger {

    private String title;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private long id;

    public Passenger() {

    }

    public Passenger(String title, String firstName, String lastName, long id) {
        this.title = title;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void enterDetails() {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your title: ");
        title = keyboard.next();
        System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");
        firstName = keyboard.next();
        System.out.print("Enter your last name: ");
        lastName = keyboard.next();
        System.out.print("Enter your ID: ");
        id = keyboard.nextLong();
    }

    public void outputDetails() {
        System.out.print();
        System.out.print("Passenger name: " + title + " " + firstName + " " + lastName);
        System.out.print("Identify Number: " + id);
        System.out.print();
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

}
```

**Demo.java**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Demo {

    public static Passenger[] passengers = new Passenger[10];
    public static Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int option = 0;

        passengers[0] = new Passenger("Mr", "Benjamin", "Parker", 12345678);
        passengers[1] = new Passenger("Mrs", "Mary", "Long", 96421368);
        passengers[2] = new Passenger(....);
        passengers[3] = new Passenger(....);
        passengers[4] = new Passenger(....);
        passengers[5] = new Passenger(....);
        passengers[6] = new Passenger(....);
        passengers[7] = new Passenger(....);

        while(option != 7) {
            System.out.println("Please select an option:"
                + "\n1) Enter passenger particulars to array"
                + "\n2) Display passenger particulars from array"
                + "\n3) Search passenger particulars using ID"
                + "\n4) Search passenger particulars using both surname and name"
                + "\n5) Display passenger particulars in ascending order of ID"
                + "\n6) Display passenger particulars in ascending order of surname"
                + "\n7) Quit
            )
            option = kb.nextInt();

            switch(option) {
                case 1:
                    inputDetails();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    outputDetails();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    searchDetailsID();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    searchDetailsName();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    sortDetailsID();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    sortDetailsName();
                    break;
                case 7:
                    System.out.println("You quitted the program!");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid input!");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void inputDetails() {
        int element = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < passengers.length; i++) {
            if(passengers[i] != null)
                element++;
        }
        passengers[element] = new Passenger();
        passengers[element].enterDetails();
        element++;
    }

    public static void outputDetails() {
        for(int i = 0; i < passengers.length; i++) {
            passengers[i].outputDetails();
        }
    }

    public static void searchDetailsID() {
        boolean isFound = false;
        System.out.print("Please enter an passenger id: ");
        long id = kb.nextLong();

        for(int i = 0; i < passengers.length; i++) {
            if(id == passengers[i].getid()) {
                passengers[i].outputDetails();
                isFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!isFound) {
            System.out.println("No passenger with that id!");
        }
    }

    public static void searchDetailsName() {
        boolean isFound = false;
        System.out.print("Please enter an passenger first name: ");
        String firstName = kb.next();
        System.out.print("Please enter an passenger last name: ");
        String lastName = kb.next();

        for(int i = 0; i < passengers.length; i++) {
            if(firstName.equalsIgnoreCase(passengers[i].getFirstName()) && lastName.equalsIgnoreCase(passengers[i].getLastName())) {
                passengers[i].outputDetails();
                isFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!isFound) {
            System.out.println("No passenger with that name!");
        }
    }

    public static void sortDetailsID() {
        long temp = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < passengers.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < passengers.length - 1; j++) {
                if(passengers[i].getId() > passengers[j].getId()) {
                    temp = passengers[i].getId();
                    passengers[i] = passengers[j];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void sortDetailsName() {

    }

}
```

Comment: Please indicate which lines are throwing the `NullPointerException`s.

Comment: @Slaw I get `NullPointerException` when i entered a `id` that doesn't exists in the Arrays into `searchDetailsID()`, when i entered a `firstName` & `lastName` that doesn't exists in the Arrays into `searchDetailsName()`, and also the second `for-loop` in `sortDetailsID`. Please note that this is NOT because I use .... from `passengers[2]` to `passengers[7]`. Thanks

Comment: The [stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors) of the NPE will tell you what line the exception is being thrown. Note that you initialize an array of length `10` but only fill indices `0` through `7` with a `Passenger` instance. That means indices `8` and `9` are `null`, yet you loop over the entire array as if none of the elements are `null`. If no ID or name match, you'll end up iterating over those `null` elements.

Comment: @Slaw alright noted. I solved the `null` error that happens in `searchDetailsID()` and `searchDetailsName()` by filling up indices `8` and `9`. However, is it possible to provide me an answer on how to complete `sortDetailsID()` and `sortDetailsName()`. For `sortDetailsID()` i pretty sure it is wrong as i simply copy from youtube tutorial where they are using `int` as examples. Thanks

Comment: Another option to filling up the entire array is keeping a record of the actual "size" of the array. The size would be the last non-null index + 1 (e.g. if all indices contain non-null elements then size = 10). Make sure there are no "gaps" in the array using this approach. Regarding `sortDetailsID()`, shouldn't `temp` be a `Passenger`? Regarding `sortDetailsName()`, see [the documentation of `String.compareTo(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Java compiler even can't compile your code so how do you get NPE? Where is `getStudentNo` method in `Passenger` class ? Why `getId` method was written as `getid` in `Demo` class? You must correct this compile time error then you can ask about semantic or NPE.

Comment: @Sam oops my apologies! have updated the coding.

Comment: @Slaw do you mean changing `long temp = 0` to `Passenger temp` on line 1 and `temp = passengers[i]` on line 4 of `sortDetailsID()`?

Comment: Your intention is to swap the elements, correct? That means you need to do `passengers[i] = passengers[j]` followed by `passengers[j] = temp`. That only works if `temp` is a `Passenger`.

Comment: Your code isn't clear. Compile your code and then post here. What is `undergraduate` array?

Comment: @Sam my apologies. i edited my code around 10 mins ago. could you kindly refresh the page. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your NPE stack trace is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.Demo.searchDetailsID(Demo.java:90)
    at com.Demo.main(Demo.java:46)
```

If you evaluate your code deeply, you will found that you initialized `passengers` array with **10** but you instance only **8**  index in `main` method of `Demo` class. In other words, NPE is thrown when your loop wants to read the **9** or **10** index from the array.
So if you replace the first line of `Demo` class with the following line, your code will work fine:

```
public static Passenger[] passengers = new Passenger[8];
```

**Solution 2 :**

Of course, you can use an if as following:

```
public static void searchDetailsID() {
        boolean isFound = false;
        System.out.print("Please enter an passenger id: ");
        long id = kb.nextLong();

        for(int i = 0; i < passengers.length; i++) {
            if(passengers[i] != null /* I append this check*/ && id == passengers[i].getId()) {
                passengers[i].outputDetails();
                isFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!isFound) {
            System.out.println("No passenger with that id!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Regarding, "_In other words, NPE is thrown when your loop wants to read the 9 or 10 index from the array_": Arrays are zero-based. Since the array has a length of 10 the max index is 9, not 10.

Comment: Yes, I mean 8 or 9 indexes and in daily we called the 9 home or 10 home :)